# wordpress custom authentication using LOGGED_IN_SALT

Tags: php, wordpress, security, authentication

I'm trying to create a Wordpress plugin that restricts access to content based on a custom username/password database.

For the authentication I'm creating 2 cookies after the user logs in - one with the user name and another with the hash(created using WP's PasswordHash library)  of the `username+'secret'`.

For the 'secret', I was planning on using one of the constants from *wp-config.php*, for example "LOGGED_IN_SALT".

My question is: Is it a security risk to used `LOGGED_IN_SALT`?  Could I compromise the security of the Wordpress installation if I do this?  Would one of the other constants be a better choice?  Should I avoid using any of these constants?

Any opinions welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use cookie for that, use session instead. If you use cookie, it can be change by client, and also it can be stolen through xss vulnerability. You can get user data from session, and validate restricted access with user data fetched from session.

When you go to restricted content, get user data from session;

```
<?php

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

// Validate content here
?>
```

Comment: I was using cookies instead of sessions purely because that's what Wordpress does (as far as I can work out).

Also, I specifically don't want to use the Wordpress user database.

Comment: You won't use wordpress user database, you will validate content by using user id in session. Probably, you have some table or metavalue for storing key => content relation in tables.

Comment: get_current_user_id() is a Wordpress function that will give the current Wordpress user id from the Wordpress database, no?

Comment: Yes but, you are checking if current user is permitted to see custom content or not right? You can validate it by using above function. You do not need to save something to cookie. Just store your user->content relation in db, and validate it by using user id

Comment: No, I'm not.  See my original question!

Comment: `restricts access to content based on a custom username/password database`